# PHP include one website into another

Tags: php, iframe, include

I'm trying to show my Dropbox Public Folder on my website, i've got the link and i'm trying to use PHP include to do it like this:

```
<?php
include("MY DROPBOX LINK");
?>
```

But nothing shows up. I'm trying to avoid iFrames and thought PHP might be cleaner

Comment: I think an iframe would be cleaner - they are meant for including one page within another.

Comment: cool, i'll probably just use an iframe then...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`include` only works with local file references (same server)*- what are you specifically after? You could use an iframe?

```
<iframe src='MY DROPBOX LINK'></iframe>
```

***OR***

To include in your application, there are also native PHP scripting means such as [here](http://elis.ws/easily-integrate-dropbox-in-your-php-application/)..and also [here](http://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=18035)

*correction: as per the comments below, you can grab external content, though it is not recommended

Comment: Exactly the same as an iframe. But i assumed a PHP include would be quicker...am i wrong?

Comment: include wont work with external content- and you wont get any dynammic effects, an iframe would be better to pull 'as is' functionality in.

Comment: If you do it server-side, the user will have to wait for your webserver to retrieve your dropbox folder, and then wait again for your webserver to deliver the rendered page to them. If you go with the iframe, the user will get your page as fast as you can send it to them, and then fetch the contents of the iframe. This way your page will load a lot faster for them.

Comment: I would say it just depends on what you're looking for. Some things to note: php gathering the page both ties of the output stream and will include the html,head and other tags (making your site presumably no longer valid). This also means the other page's CSS and won't work now that it's embeded. Iw ould recommend just sticking with an iFrame.

Comment: AFAIK, you can include external files, but is not recommended (and disabled in php for security reasons). In php.ini, allow_url_include = 1 
allow_url_fopen = 1 would be the related settings. They are not recommended however.

Comment: @JP19: "...If "URL fopen wrappers" are enabled in PHP (which they are in the default configuration)..." say the docs. But anyway they are really a risk.

Comment: You'll have to echo html to client browser: echo '<iframe src="http://dropbox/path"></iframe>';

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be looking at using the Dropbox API for this. There is some PHP code [here](http://code.google.com/p/dropbox-php/wiki/Dropbox_API) which should be a good starting point.

Comment: I already have, however my web host is in the process of enabling (or telling me that they cant support it) Oauth for PHP so i can use the API

Answer (score 0):

If you can install the php-curl module (or already have it), that seems the best option to me without iframes.